# CUBE dimension reduction with sequential slices

Tags: sql, mdx, dax, cube, ssas-tabular

I have data in a cube, organized across 5 axes:

- Source (data provider)
- GEO (country)
- Product (A or B)
- Item (Sales, Production, Sales_national)
- Date

In short, I have multiple data providers for different Product, Item, GEO and Date, i.e. for different slices of the cube.
Not all "sources" cover all dates, product, countries. Some will have more up to date information, but it will be preliminary.

The core of the problem is to have a synthesis of what all sources say.

Importantly, the choice of data provide for each "slice" of the cube is made by the user/analyst and needs to be so (business knowledge of provider methodology, quality etc).

What I am looking for, is a way to create a 'central dictionary' with all the calculation-types.

Such dictionary would be organized like this:

```
 Operation          Source      GEO Item    Product     Date_start  Date_end
Assign              Source3     ITA Sales   Product_A   01/01/2016  01/01/2017
Assign              Source1     ITA Sales   Product_A   01/01/2017  last
Assign with %delta  Source2     ITA Sales   Product_A   01/01/2018  last
```

This means:

- From Jan2016 to Jan 2017, ProdA Sales in Italy, take Source 3
- From Jan17 to last available, take Source 1
- From Jan18 to last available, take the existing, add %difference across time from Source 2

The data and calculation are examples, there are other more complex, but the gist of it is putting slices of the "Source" 5-dimensional cube into a "Target" 4-dimensional cube, with a set of sequential calculations.

In SQL, it is the equivalent of a bunch of filtered SELECTs + INSERT, but the complexity of the calculations will probably lead to lots of nested JOINS.

The solution will be most likely custom functions, but I was wondering if anyone is aware of a language or software other than DAX/MDX which would allow to do this with minimal customization?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you opposed to DAX/MDX or just looking for other options?

Comment: not opposed - just wanted to check that there is not some obvious out-of-the-box solution, framework or language that I am ignoring